# sbt multi project: create resource in another sub-project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt project with two sub-projects, A and B.  A produces a standalone scala-based executable exe.  When exe is run, it will produce a file out.xml.  I want this file to be part of resources for project B.  I **do not** want B to include any references to A's code, all I want is the out.xml file to be part of it.  I suspect that http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html should be a good starting point, but I can't get my head around on how to split it between two projects.  Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

Since A is a dependency of the build process, which needs to run the executable to generate your xml file you would list it as a libraryDepencency in `project/[something].sbt` or `project/project/[something].scala`. This would make it available to code you put in `build.sbt` or `project/[something].scala` but not make it a transitive dependency of the resulting artifact of project B.

(Or you could of course make project A a sbt-plugin itself, or create yet another project which is a plugin depending on A that runs the executable.)

Comment: So you are saying, that sub-project A should be a library dependency of the root project? What would be the syntax for making a sub-project such a dependency?

Comment: No, make A an SBT plugin project, add as a plugin in project B. Check out the SBT docs for details: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html